# How to use file_get_contents() with non-ASCII characters in URL?

Tags: php, html, encoding

I currentley trying to get data from a website, and use it in my PHP script.

The link I am trying to reach is: 
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=★%20Bayonet

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$skin = $_GET['market_hash_name'];
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$skin."";
$FN = file_get_contents($link);

echo $FN;
?>
```

And this is how I use my link:

`http://myhost.com/getPrice.php?market_hash_name=★ Bayonet`

This is the error I am getting:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=â˜… Bayonet): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in F:\xampp\htdocs\getPrice.php on line 5

EDIT:

Okay, so I have found a solution for my problem, but now a new error is comming up:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85+Bayonet+%7C+Stained (Factory New)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in F:\xampp\htdocs\getPrice.php on line 7

This is how I am using my link now:

> getPrice.php?market_hash_name=★ Bayonet | Stained

And this is my code:

```
function getPrice($string) {
$skin = urlencode($_GET['market_hash_name']);
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$skin." ".$string;
$content = file_get_contents($link);
$data = json_decode($content, true);
return $data['lowest_price'];
}
$FN = getPrice("(Factory New)");
$MW = getPrice("(Minimal Wear)");
$FT = getPrice("(Field-Tested)");
$WW = getPrice("(Well-Worn)");
$BS = getPrice("(Battle-Scarred)");


echo "Factory New: $FN; Minimal Wear: $MW; Field-Tested: $FT; Well-Worn: $WW; Battle-Scared: $BS";
```

Comment: `http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet`

Comment: Try to set unicode caractère instead of copy/paste this weather caractère : &#9733;

Comment: As per your edit, you'll need to use Curl then.

Comment: Care to place an example?

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/14953867/ - You can further your research by simply Googling "curl website php". You will find plenty of results, some of which may lead you back to other Q&A's on Stack.

Comment: I have tried, but this is the response I get when using CURL: ‹ªV*.MNN-.V²JKÌ)N­ÿÿòÊC4

Answer (score 1):

Among other characters, non-ASCII characters **must** be [URL-encoded (aka percent-encoded)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in query strings.

```
$skin = url_encode($_GET['market_hash_name']);
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$skin."";
$FN = file_get_contents($link);
```