# php Curl pass http cookie

Tags: php, curl

after a user logged into my website a session is started with name "xy-login".

I now want to use cURL to get the content of another webressource which accepts the same session (F.e. xylogin=lqb3a4fma4ggf4rr49ktfggel).

With wget I would do something like this:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
$contents = file_get_contents('http://localhst/xy/print', false, $context);
```

But how would I need to change this function to pass the session (as with wget)?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953910/1474777

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

    $options = array(

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```