# PHP: How to detect a website redirect that returns a '404' status code?

Tags: php, redirect

I am writing a small php script that can distinguish two between different kinds of responses from a third-party website.

For the human visitor, recognizing the difference is fairly easy: Response #1 is a bare-bones 404 error page, whereas response #2 redirects to the main page.

For my script, this turns out to be somewhat more difficult. Both types return a '404' status code, file_get_contents() returns empty for both and the "redirect" doesn't really register as a redirect (like I said, there's a '404' status code, not a '30X'). Get_headers() shows no distinction, either (no "Location:" or anything of that sort).

Any way I can get this done?

Comment: Look at `get_headers($the_URL, 0);`

Comment: Are you using cURL to retrieve this external webpage?

Comment: Post the URLs to have a look on what they respond.

Comment: As posted above, get_headers() shows no distinction, and I am using file_get_contents() to retrieve the page. Should I try cURL instead?

Comment: @axiac: Sending you a message in a moment.

Comment: How do I send messages, and is there a way to actually get notified if there are comments? I absolutely adore this site when I'm in read-only mode, but every time I try to post here, it kills me.

Comment: @Brokenstuff I think it doesn't provide a way to send private messages.

Comment: @Brokenstuff  If you use the desktop version of the website then there are two small notification areas on the left of the black bar on the top of the page (just after the "Stack Exchange" logo). The first one shows (on red background) the number of unread comments you have (comments on your questions or answers or comments that mention your username). The other one shows on green background the number of reputation points you received. These icons exists in the mobile page too but they don't display anything, you have to tap on them. I don't know how it is on the mobile app, I don't use it.

Comment: I can see the icons fine, but since I'm an infrequent visitor, I'd really need the system to send me mail notifications. My preferences are set to send me any unread stuff from my inbox, but I'm afraid it doesn't happen for me. Makes me feel kinda bad because that way I might accidentally abandon my own tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do a redirect:

- the `HTTP` response codes for redirect (usually `301` and `302`) accompanied by the `Location:` header that contains the URL

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Location: http://www.example.org
  ```
- the `HTTP` header [`Refresh:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Refresh); it contains a number of seconds to wait and the new URL:

  ```
  Refresh: 0; url=http://www.example.org
  ```
- the [`HTML` `meta`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) element that emulates the Refresh HTTP header:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.org">
  ```
- Javascript:

  ```
  <script>document.location = 'http://www.example.org';</script>
  ```

  Note that there are countless possibilities to redirect using Javascript. What is common to all of them is the usage of the `location` property of [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) or [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). `location` is an object of type [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) that can be assigned directly using a string or can be changed using its `href` property or its methods `assign()` and `replace()`.

If the requests to your URLs does not return any content, the both return status code `404` and no `Location:` header then check for the presence of the `Refresh:` header in the response.

You better use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make the requests instead of `file_get_contents()`. `curl` provides a better control of the headers sent and received.

Comment: Thanks a ton - that did the trick. I used some code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953867/how-to-get-page-content-using-curl - then I sent the results through htmlspecialchars() and now I have the entire output I can work with. Turns out the redirect was done via Javascript (window.location).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest You to make a `cURL` request to desired site and see what kind of response it is.

As described in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php),

```
curl_getinfo ($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

will give You an associative array, in it You will find the `http_code` key, which will hold Your status code.

If redirect case will give You non-30X status code, You can try to fetch redirect url by this:

```
curl_getinfo ($handle, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
```