# Modified PHP get_meta_tags not working for some URLs

Tags: php, regex, meta-tags

I am trying to use the code from the [user contributed notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php#117176) on php.net for the [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) function. From what it seems, if the meta tag is formatted `<meta content="foo" name="bar" />` then the code will miss it. Currently, only tags formatted as `<meta name="bar" content="foo"/>` will work. I'm not great with regex and tried unsuccessfully to fix it. Here is an example of a [url](http://thenationshealth.aphapublications.org/content/45/6/1.4.long) that seems to slip through the regex. Apologies in advance that my question isn't necessarily about the `get_meta_tags` function but it seems that this may be losely related to some of the other issues people have been having with that function.

It seems like the problem is somewhere around here:

```
preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*(name|property)="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);
```

which may need to be something like:

```
preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*(name|property|content)="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . '(content|name)="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);
```

But again, I'm pretty terrible with regex. Any ideas?

Comment: You would be better off using a DOM-aware library and fetching all meta tags that way.

Comment: Not exactly a dupe but this answer can be used to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/3711554/1182891

Comment: What worked for me was posted here and then it disappeared? I used regex "lookaround". [https://eval.in/412736](https://eval.in/412736)

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php

Comment: @JohnR Yes, I removed it and put to the [notes at manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php#117766), because I was too tired to write long explanation :] As you write, it's what you're looking for, restored my answer. Also see [regex faq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638) if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to capture meta name/property inside a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for being independent of sequence:

```
function extract_meta_tags($source)
{
  $pattern = '
  ~<\s*meta\s

  # using lookahead to capture type to $1
    (?=[^>]*?
    \b(?:name|property|itemprop|http-equiv)\s*=\s*
    (?|"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"|\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\'|
    ([^"\'>]*?)(?=\s*/?\s*>|\s\w+\s*=))
  )

  # capture content to $2
  [^>]*?\bcontent\s*=\s*
    (?|"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"|\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\'|
    ([^"\'>]*?)(?=\s*/?\s*>|\s\w+\s*=))
  [^>]*>

  ~ix';

  if(preg_match_all($pattern, $source, $out))
    return array_combine(array_map('strtolower', $out[1]), $out[2]);
  return array();
}
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oE4oU9/2). Used the [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) feature for extracting values of different quote styles.

`print_r(extract_meta_tags($str));` Try with some different data [at eval.in](https://eval.in/414221)

---

Use this on html `<head>` section. To get page source and extract head:

1.) Get source by using [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953910/3110638), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#refsect1-function.fsockopen-examples).

2.) Extract `<head>` by using [dom](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) or regex [like this:](https://regex101.com/r/bI6sE5/2) `(?is)<head\b[^>]*>(.*?)</head>`

3.) Extract meta tags from `<head>` by using provided regex or [try with a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/3110638).