# Get page content from URL

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I can get YouTube video ID what my API prints out. I want to get page content, not source code. If someone want to see how it looks, here is API URL: http://fnapi.cpt-design.tk/api.php

I have this so far

```
<?php $id = NULL;
      $channel_id = 'UCd_09Tp1Bk05gDqc1RWyhuw';
      $xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=%s';, $channel_id));
      if (!empty($xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0])){
        $id = $xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0];
      }
      echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're going to need more details (and more in depth explanation, also what code you have so far) of what you're really looking for.

Comment: @DavidGomes http://pastebin.com/iHvx3vJR
It's my only code. I want to print out this id using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If this page located at the same domain you can use answer by smarx.

If you want to get page content from other domain. You should use PHP => cURL

[How to get page content using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953867/how-to-get-page-content-using-curl)

Or if it's your domain you can send

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

with your response.

Comment: I want get page content using JQuery :/ Not cURL. I can't use it because I'm creating browser extension.

Comment: if i understand, you want to get youtube.com page content, then you can't get page content using javascript. XSS protection. Cross site contents can not be read by javascript. No major browser will allow you that. Or if you want to get youtube video id from this api, and its your domain, you should send allow-cross-origin header with your response

Comment: Yeah! That's it what i want! I want to access my own page and get it's content. There's only YouTube video ID. Do you know how to send that header and get this ID?

Answer (score 0):

From a page on the same domain, this should work:

```
$.get('http://fnapi.cpt-design.tk/api.php').done(function (id) {
  console.log(id);
});
```

From another domain, you'll first have to modify the API to support CORS by adding a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

In PHP, this means putting this line at the top of your code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: It's on different domain, because I'm creating browser extension.

Comment: Well, the API doesn't support CORS, so it can't be called from JavaScript on another domain. That said, I think browser extensions can typically make cross-origin requests anyway... what browser are you writing an extension for? And is this JavaScript you're injecting into a page or code that runs in the background? You might want to share your actual code.

Comment: I am creating extension for Opera.
Here's my actual code: http://pastebin.com/T7KSGqRb
And - Yes, that code runs in the background.

Comment: If you own the API, the easiest thing is probably just to add CORS support. (Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.)