# Return source code from POST form landing page

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm trying to get information from a web form. The website is a public search form, where you can look up cars in Denmark and get some basic information about the car.

If you look at the source code, there is a hidden field called `'dmrFormToken'` with a random token. I extracted this token, and I include this in the POST request. Here is my current code to simulate a POST request in PHP with this cUrl script.

```
<?php
// Source: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');

/* Get Form Token */
$formUrl = "https://motorregister.skat.dk/dmr-front/appmanager/skat/dmr?_nfpb=true&_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vis_koeretoej_side&_nfls=false";
$dmrFormToken = file_get_html($formUrl)->find('input[name=dmrFormToken]')[0]->value;

//extract data from the post
//set POST variables
$url = "https://motorregister.skat.dk/dmr-front/appmanager/skat/dmr?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=kerne_vis_koeretoej&kerne_vis_koeretoej_actionOverride=%2Fdk%2Fskat%2Fdmr%2Ffront%2Fportlets%2Fkoeretoej%2Fnested%2FfremsoegKoeretoej%2Fsearch&_pageLabel=vis_koeretoej_side";
$fields = array(
  urlencode('dmrFormToken') => urlencode($dmrFormToken),
  urlencode('kerne_vis_koeretoejwlw-radio_button_group_key:{actionForm.soegekriterie}') => urlencode("REGISTRERINGSNUMMER"),
  urlencode('kerne_vis_koeretoej{actionForm.soegeord}') => urlencode("AZ87303"),
  urlencode('kerne_vis_koeretoejactionOverride:search') => urlencode("Søg")
);
$fields_string = "";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

//print response
echo $result;
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
This document you requested has moved temporarily.

It's now at https://motorregister.skat.dk/dmr-front/appmanager/skat/dmr?_nfls=false&_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vis_koeretoej_side.
```

I've downloaded the LiveHttpHeaders extensions for FireFox, which allows me to follow the request. Here is the result

[image]

Here is the POST request content from LiveHttpHeaders and from the cUrl script above:

```
LiveHTTPHeaders:
dmrFormToken=5l1bq8pllh54kciahlu8lml3ou&kerne_vis_koeretoejwlw-radio_button_group_key%3A%7BactionForm.soegekriterie%7D=REGISTRERINGSNUMMER&kerne_vis_koeretoej%7BactionForm.soegeord%7D=AZ87303&kerne_vis_koeretoejactionOverride%3Asearch=S%C3%B8g

cUrl Script: // echo $fields_string;
dmrFormToken=s6qghv0013ch7u3pcsineao6lu&kerne_vis_koeretoejwlw-radio_button_group_key%3A%7BactionForm.soegekriterie%7D=REGISTRERINGSNUMMER&kerne_vis_koeretoej%7BactionForm.soegeord%7D=AZ87303&kerne_vis_koeretoejactionOverride%3Asearch=S%C3%B8g
```

How can I receive the source code from the target URL with my custom POST request

The question thread suggested below doesnt solve the problem. I've able to make a POST request to my own test page, but once I try it on the https://motorregister.skat.dk/ it doesnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get page content using cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953867/how-to-get-page-content-using-curl)

Comment: I am able to do it on a test page with a form using POST, but not on the website i linked in the question description (DMR)

Answer (score 0):

Have a go including this line in your Curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: This just leads be back to the start page with the form on it, and not the destination with the information about the car